# SqlFunctions.IsNumeric question

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'vw just use SqlFunctions.IsNumeric.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric.aspx) you can see that it returns int?.
Why does `SqlFunctions.IsNumeric` returns `int?` and not `bool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be on par with how [`ISNUMERIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)  behaves in MS-SQL - it also returns an INT.

Comment: Behaves also like `ISNUMERIC('$12')` ?

Comment: @pst Yes. "This function is translated to a corresponding function in the database." So in EF, it actually uses the ISNUMERIC function.

Answer (score 1):

This is how [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function is defined in SQL. It returns int.